# How did they solve this double integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How did they solve this double integral?

**Solved Equation:**
$$
D=\frac{60\times10^{-6}}{2\pi r^2}\cdot\int\limits_{\color{#0AF}{0}}^{\color{#0AF}{2\pi}}\int\limits_{\color{#C00}{0}}^{\color{#C00}\infty}rdr\color{#0AF}{d\phi}=\frac{60\times10^{-6}}{2\pi\color{#C00}{r^2}}\cdot\frac{\color{#C00}{r^2}}2\int\limits_{\color{#0AF}{0}}^{\color{#0AF}{2\pi}}\color{#0AF}{d\phi}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
D
&=\frac{60\times10^{-6}}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{\color{#0AF}{2\pi}}2\\
&=30\times10^{-6}
\end{align}
$$

When I try to solve for this, the result is divergent.

Comment: You're new, so you don't know.  You must *TYPESET* equations using *MathJax* so your question can be searched by the algorithms on this site.  Also, you must show your own work.

Comment: No... posting a picture is *NOT* appropriate... as the search algorithms can "read" it.  You *MUST* typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll delete this and I'll post a new one.

Comment: Just typeset here and you'll be fine.

Comment: Hi Abdul.  We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: I have converted the image to MathJax. Please read the posts on how to use MathJax and use that in future posts.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty r\,\mathrm{d}r$ is indeed divergent. There are other scope and binding errors involving $r$ in the evaluation of that integral. Where did this solution come from?